# SCAN and LOOK disk scheduling

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, disk

Suppose the disk is idle but has a direction that the read head was heading in before it became idle.
(Say the read-head is in sector 5 and previously read sector 1, but there are no requests now.)
When a request comes, will the read head continue in the direction it was heading before, or can it choose the other direction?
(Say a request comes for sector 4, in the example, would it then have to continue in positive direction or could it start reversing at once?)
LOOK would simply return, but should SCAN go all the way to the end?

Also, say I'm heading outwards (from 1 to 100) and I am heading for sector 90 but before I get there another request appears that is between mi current position and sector 90, do I read that and then head for 90, or do I keep going to 90 and then head back?

Comment: It is really difficult to figure out what you are asking.

Comment: Hunter, You don't understand the question or do you think it's hard to find out the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first scenario (you have no pending I/O, disk is at cylinder 5) going outwards and a request to cylinder 4 comes:

- With SCAN the head of the disk would still need to go to the last cylinder and then go back to cylinder 4
- With LOOK as there were no more requests it can reverse direction to service request at cylinder 4

In your second scenario (you are heading outwards to cylinder 90 but before you get there another request appears between your current position and cylinder 90):

In this case with either SCAN or LOOK you would service all the requests waiting to be serviced which are located under the current head position. Therefore in your example it would service the second request before servicing the one at cylinder 90.

Comment: Ok, got the second part. Basicaly the first part was if in SCAN the disk keeps turning when there are no requests or if it stops until a new request appears

Comment: @Grulli: that is not prescribed. Usually the disk keeps spinning for a while before it parks its heads, so from that point it depends on the specific implementation. Anyways when you study disk scheduling you usually assume that there are a bunch of requests pending.